# Why is this get method invocation (c#) giving me an error?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Working in Unity and can't figure out how to change the value of the "name" property of the "Dialogue" object I created. Apparently the name "does not exist in the current context" for some reason.

Code snippet from class `DialogueTrigger`:

```
public class DialogueTrigger : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Dialogue dialogue1 = new Dialogue();
    dialogue1.Name = "David"; // THIS IS WHERE I AM GETTING "the name dialogue1.Name does not exist in current context"
```

Code snippet from class Dialogue (no errors here):

```
public class Dialogue
{
    public string name;
    public string Name    // the Name property
    {
        get => name;
        set => name = value;
    }
```

Thanks for any help you can give!

Comment: The code you posted isn't legal. If that's really the code you're trying to compile, you need to put the assignment statement `dialogue1.Name = "David";` into a method, where it would be legal. It's not legal outside of a method. If that's not the code you're trying to compile, fix the post so that it is.

Comment: Just checked my Assets folder and there is no other CS file with the name Dialogue. No idea.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Thank you, that was it. It needs to be in a method. :)